# Angular 2: Rendering angular html components from webservice

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am looking for how to add html which is a return of the web service, in angular. The problem is that the angular directives do not rendered. here is my source code

```
//tohtml.directive.ts

import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appToHtml]'
})
export class ToHtmlDirective {
constructor( private el: ElementRef) {}


tohtml() {
  //it is assumed that this is the return of the webservice
  this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<a 
  [routerLink]="/link/to/page">helpful!
   </a>';
  }
}
```

Code for component.html

```
<div id="wrapper">

<h1 appToHtml>
  Hello World!
</h1>
</div>
```

the code works, but the rendering of the [routerLink] does not work, pleaseee hellppp !!!

Comment: Is this the original code, which does not work?

Comment: Do you get any errors, or does the rendering just fail silently?

Comment: That won't work because you're rendering the routerLink as html, it needs to be rendered first. You could achieve this from a function that navigates to a route

Comment: there is no errors, @WesleyCoetzee: An exemple pleasee!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting innerHTML prop in your directive you only set DOM and attributes. But this content need to be compile by angular to allow angular-like behavior (binding directives, instanciating components etc..) .

Angular dont have compiler ready to use like angularJS ( which has $compile ). You need to use 3rd party libraries like

https://www.npmjs.com/package/p3x-angular-compile

or

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dynamic-template

Those lib comes with handy examples. You should easily understand how to use them.
Be aware that you cant use AOT with such a rendering system.

Edition for ngx-dynamic-template usage :

if your dynamic templates need some directive of component, you have to configure ngx-dynamic-template to import the corresponding modules.

You can create a dynamic module like that in your case

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class DynamicModule {}
```

and then when importing ngx in your appModule or SharedModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        NgxDynamicTemplateModule.forRoot({extraModules: [DynamicModule]})
        ...
    ],
```

Then you will be able to use routerLink without problem (i just tested)

```
in cmpt : 
htmlTemplate = `<a [routerLink]="['dress-options']">link to user component</a>`;

in template : 
<div dynamic-template [template]="htmlTemplate"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i implement the compiler p3x-angular-compile, but no result, thats don't compile routerlink

Comment: i never tried p3x-angular-compile but i have already use ngx-dynamic-template and it worked fine. Is the routerModule correctly imported on your app ?

Comment: yes my rooterModule is correctly imported and work fine, for ngx-dynamic-template, its generate me Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /node_modules/ngx-dynamic-template/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3.
Any suggestion  ??

Comment: Hello, this is the config
"ngx-dynamic-template": "^2.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4", "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",

Comment: Hello, i just upgrade to angular5, and i test the exmple of ngx-dynamic-template 2.2.0 and its work, but with routerLink its make error Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
theres a link with same issu with me 
(https://github.com/apoterenko/ngx-dynamic-template/issues/54)

Answer (score 0):

With the latest angular version for me only this module works fine: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dynamic-template
v2.1.24 for angular4, v.2.3.0 is for angular5