# Trying to load component in angular 5 using innerHtml. But html page is not able to render the <app-my></app-my> selector

Tags: angular, angular5

```
    component.html
            <div *ngIf="flagArray[i].showDiv == true>
            <div id=div1 [innerHTML]="getContent(data.name)"></div>
            </div>


    component.ts
              constructor() {

                this.selectedIndex = -1;
                this.flagArray[0].showDiv = true;
                this.dataArray = [
               {name: 'Account Type', content: 'id=accntType', tag :'<div>Hello
               <app-accountType></app-accountType></div>'}
              ]

                for(let  i=1; i<this.dataArray.length; i++){
                  this.flagArray[i].showDiv = false;
                }
              }

              getContent(name): any {
                for(let p of this.dataArray) {
                  console.log(" Value of Id >>"+name+ " Value of p"+p.name);
                  if (p.name === name) {
                    document.getElementById('accnttype').innerHTML='<div>Hello--<app-accountType></app-accountType></div>';
                  }
                }
              }

    account.component.ts
    @Component({
       selector: 'app-accountType',
       templateUrl: '../accountType/accountType.component.html',
    })

account.component.html
<div>Hell from Account Type </div>
```

I have added div tag from html and the methods from the .ts file. I am trying to load  into the html file. On the Html file the  should be replaced with actual code within app-accountType compoment.

Comment: innerHTML insert HTML in the DOM, it doesn't "compile" angular elements.  Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Rendering angular html components from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407908/angular-2-rendering-angular-html-components-from-webservice)

Comment: I have refereed the link, they have suggested to use third Party lib, But i dont want to use third party lib. What method shall i follow in order to achieve this?

Comment: you can follow this guide https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader and see if it matches your needs. But if you want something more dynamic, you will have to use a third party lib of mimic their logic ( but there is no gain to mimic them instead of use them )